# python / getting QThread : Destroyed while thread is still running but only on older version of python

Tags: python, python-3.8, qthread

im trying to close a qthread using ctypes. (i know its not recommended but i needed to use it)
the below code works fine on python 3.10 but its giving me QThread : Destroyed while thread is still running on python 3.8. can someone tell me what im doing wrong and how to fix it?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import time
import sys
import ctypes


class Mainthread(QThread):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.running = None

    def run(self):
        
        self.threadid = int(self.currentThreadId())
     
                    
        while self.running:

          print ("test")
          time.sleep(1)



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.funcstart()

        time.sleep(3)

        self.funcstop()    

        
    def funcstart(self):
        self.mainthread = Mainthread(self)
        self.mainthread.running = True
        self.mainthread.start()

    def funcstop(self):

        ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(self.mainthread.threadid,ctypes.py_object(SystemExit))

  
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainwindow = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```